# How to store SecureString in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating an application in .net core 2.1 along with SQL server 2016. Now I am storing some secure data in SQL server like secret keys. I am already hashing the strings using hash functions but I recently heard about SecureString and I found it very useful. So my question is I am accepting the secret key in string and I like to convert it to SecureString using the following extension method and store SecureString in SQL server using entity framework code first approach. How can I do that?

Extension method for converting string to SecureString:

```
public static SecureString ToSecureString(this string value)
{
        var secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach(char c in value)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return secureString;
}
```

Comment: What kind of values are you trying to store that way? I hope you aren’t going to use this for passwords. Other than that, I would recommend you to use a proper symmetric encryption method as secure strings aren’t exactly safe. They are just used to avoid having the content visible directly in memory.

Comment: yeah, I am not storing passwords but some other subscription keys like client secrets. Is there anyway to save them in SQL server?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What benefit do you think having this data in a SecureString has, and why do you want to send a SecureString (which, as @poke indicates, is an in-memory thing) to a database? What problem are you actually, exactly trying to solve?

Comment: Ok, so let me add some more info. I am accepting secret key in string in my controller. Now I want to convert that string in SecureString so that it will be invisible in memory. Also I am hashing that string and storing it in SQL server. So is SecureString is of any good use here? if yes, how should I use it?

Comment: For encryption purposes on the SQL end, there's column encryption, Always Encrypted and encrypted connections (SSL), but as far as I know none of the SQL client classes in either .NET Core or .NET Framework support processing `SecureString`s, so you'll have to decrypt them before transmission anyway, even if they're immediately re-encrypted to go out over the wire -- and decrypting them into a regular `String` of course defeats the original purpose. This is unfortunately another instance of `SecureString` promising more than it can actually deliver.

Comment: Your extension method implies that you've already got a `string` somewhere supplied insecurely. Converting it to a `SecureString` will do nothing about the original `string` instance floating around in memory unprotected. Unfortunately, using `SecureString` effectively is anything but simple. It's typically more trouble than it's worth -- you're better off investing in making the server and the application as isolated as possible, so you don't have to worry about people snooping memory in the first place, and keeping encrypted data encrypted at all times where you don't need it unencrypted.

Comment: So my question is in what scenarios do we use SecureString? and is there way to directly accept the secret key in SecureString like public SecureString SecretKey{get;set;}

Comment: Very rarely. About the only real scenarios I can think of are reading a password from keyboard or stream input, or generating an encryption key. In both cases the `SecureString` should exist for only a very short time while it's used for authentication purposes. For everything else, you're probably better off immediately hashing or encrypting the input in managed code, instead of putting it in a `SecureString`. Most ways managed code has for getting strings do not also support outputting `SecureString`s -- the best you can hope for is `char[]` buffers that can be cleared out.

Comment: Secure strings are really only meant for mitigating very specific attack vectors, but none of those really apply to a web application where you would receive the input directly through the network. I’d say you should forget abou secure strings in this case and use proper encryption if you want to secure the data _within_ the database.

Comment: Good rule of thumb: if you don't know when you actually should use `SecureString` it's most likely you shouldn't be using `SecureString`. As @poke points out, it's only for very specific attack vectors. If the string is ever in memory in plain text, it's already too late for `SecureString` to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the value of column using key as shown in below link

[Encryption and Decryption In SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f8fa6c/data-encryption-and-decryption-in-C-Sharp/